# Update Statement with max

Tags: sql

My table looks like

```
Product Id   Status     Line N0     startDate   ENDdate
1            Ordered       3        01/02/1999   NULL
1            Leased        1        02/04/2006   NULL
1            SubLeased     4        12/31/2000   NULL
1            Cancelled     9        10/25/2003   NULL
2            Deliverd      5        01/02/1999   NULL
2            LOST          3        02/04/2001   NULL
2            Cancelled     4        12/31/2000   NULL
```

I need to write an update statement where
If the status is cancelled Product End Date is StartDate of max(linenumber)

Result should look like

```
ProductId     EndDate
1             10/25/2003  Date of line number(9)
2             01/02/1999  Date of line number(5)
```

Thanks

Comment: What RDBMS you are using? Also do you want to delete other rows?

Comment: First try writing the `SELECT` statement which will return the results you want and then simply modify the `SELECT` statement into an `UPDATE`.

Comment: How did you get `02/04/2006` *for* `productId 1` if it is `StartDate of max(linenumber)`?

Comment: Using sql server. end date should be 10/25/2003 for ProductId 1

Comment: You need all the lines for the specific product updated or just the `Cancelled` line?

Comment: I need to update only the end date of cancelled line. but I need to get all the lines as the value of end date will be based on line number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Products which have a `Cancelled` row are given by:

```
select distinct productid from tbl where status='Cancelled'
```

The maximum line no for those is:

```
select productid,max(lineno) n from tbl
where productid in (select distinct productid from tbl where status='Cancelled')
group by productid
```

The corresponding `startdate` is given by:

```
select a.productid pid,b.n,a.startdate d from tbl a
join (
  select productid,max(lineno) n from tbl
  where productid in (
    select distinct productid from tbl 
    where status='Cancelled'
    )
  group by productid
  )b on (a.productid=b.productid and a.lineno=b.n)
```

Finally, to update `tbl` according to this, you should:

```
update tbl set enddate=d
from (
  select a.productid pid,b.n,a.startdate d from tbl a
  join (
    select productid,max(lineno) n from tbl
    where productid in (
      select distinct productid from tbl 
      where status='Cancelled'
      )
    group by productid
    )b on (a.productid=b.productid and a.lineno=b.n)
 ) t
where productid=t.pid
```

If you only need the row with the relevant `lineno` updated, add `and lineno=t.n` to the `where` clause.